# Number of whistles by referees defined in the rules or is it just a guideline?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

When starting a game a whistle is blown by the referee only once. At the end of the 1st half the referee blows the whistle 2 times. At the end of the game the referee blows the whistle 3 times.

Is this in "The Laws of the Game" or is it just a guideline?

Comment: BTW, it's not a guideline either. The three whistles for full-time is simply a convention.

Answer (score 7):

In the **Law 5: The Referee** section of [IFAB Laws of the Game](http://www.theifab.com/laws)  there is no mention of the number of whistles by referee.

In **Body Language, Communication and Whistle** subsection of the appendix section **Practical Guidelines for Match Officials** only the occasions for a whistle are listed, however the number of whistles again isn't mentioned anywhere in the Laws of the Game.

> The whistle is needed to:
>
> - start play (1st and 2nd half of normal play and extra time), after    a goal
> - stop play:
>
>   - for a free kick or penalty kick
>   - if the match is suspended or abandoned
>   - at the end of each half
> - restart play for:
>
>   - free kicks when the appropriate distance is required
>   - penalty kicks
> - restart play after it has been stopped for a:
>
>   - caution or sending-off
>   - injury
>   - substitution